# Trying to json_encode in PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is my small script

```
$item="Inception";

$query="SELECT * FROM items WHERE item = '{$item}' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $item_id = $row['items_id'];
}   

$sql="SELECT AVG(rating) AS AverageRating FROM ratings WHERE item_id = '{$item_id}'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

print(json_encode($row));
```

The output is this:

```
 {"0":"4.5","AverageRating":"4.5"}
```

My question is:  Where is row "0" coming from?  Is this normal?

Comment: try `var_dump($row);` right before the `print()` and you'll see its contents

Comment: Try print_r($row) and you might see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_fetch_array returns both a string association and a numeric association. Try mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_row alone.

Comment: Good call, mysql_fetch_assoc got rid of the unneccasarey info.  {"AverageRating":"4.3"}

Answer (score 2):

It is normal. `mysql_fetch_array` returns the row with both numeric and associative indexes. That's not an O, but a 0, meaning the first returned column.

Comment: I'm sorry, I knew it was a 0 and meant to type that.  But you answered where it came from so it seems the encoding on the php end is ok! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See the doc of [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php): by default, it returns an array with both numeric and strings indexes. If you want only an associative array, use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) or add MYSQL_ASSOC as second parameter of mysql_fetch_array.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because, as the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) states, by default `mysql_fetch_array` returns both an associative array and a numeric one.  If you just want the associative results, you can pass an extra parameter, like so:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Or if you just want the array indexed numerically:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

with

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

and the zero will be gone.

The are 3 result types you can choose from. **MYSQL_NUM** which will return a numerical array, **MYSQL_ASSOC** which will return an associative array and is also what you appear to need, and **MYSQL_BOTH** which is the default and returns both.